# Getting separate tables for each element of a list

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have done a map function which gives me a list. I want to convert each one of the elements of the list into a table to export with markdown.

I have this list:

```
mtcars_list <- c ("am","gear","carb")
```

I have the variable I want to group_by for: "cyl" And the variable I want to summarise. In this case I will transform the variable "vs" of the mtcars database as a factor:

```
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs , levels=c('0', '1'))
```

I then do this map:: purr function,

```
df1 <- purrr::map(mtcars_list, ~ mtcars %>% select(cyl,vs,!!sym(.x)) %>% 
                    mutate(n=n() , .by=c(cyl, .data[[.x]], vs)) %>% 
                    mutate(n2=n(), .by=c(cyl, .data[[.x]]) ) %>% 
                    group_by(cyl, .data[[.x]], vs) %>% 
                    slice_tail(n=1) %>% 
                    mutate(perc=(n/n2)*100) %>% 
                    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(cyl,.data[[.x]]), names_from = vs, values_from = perc)
)
```

However when I run the output with markdown, it prints only the list with the code for the whole list, and I cannot split the results in separate tables for each of the elements of the list.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "separate tables"?

Comment: @jay.sf A different  data.frame (or table) for each of the elements of the list (am, gear and vs)

Comment: For what reason, it's not advisable, just keep it in the list. You can use `knitr::kable(df1, format='html') |> kableExtra::kable_styling()`, but not exactly sure what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. But in that case I obtain all the columns and rows together in a data frame and I only want each list separately (the element [1], [2], etc...)

Comment: You're probably looking for `list2env()` but it's really not advisable. Why would you clutter your workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You probably still need to explicitly `print` (or some other function with side effects, viz. output) `df1`. What about this code chunk:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
 walk(df1, print)
```
````

(`walk` also provided by {purrr})